# how to extract array type in an array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

How can i filter the name, only keep the array type in an newArray?

```
let data = [
  {name: 'Andy', details: [{age: 20, sex: "male"}]},
  {name: 'John', details: [{age: 25, sex: "male"}]},
];

//Output result
let newArray = [{age:20, sex: "male"}, {age:25, sex: "male"}];
```

I try to complete the details.. how it can help. =)

Comment: What's the expected result ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reduce` like this:

```
let result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr.details],[])
```

Comment: Cool. It solve my problem.

Comment: glad, it could help. choose it as answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand your question. Try to use ES5 map method:

```
let data = [
    {name: 'Andy', details: [{age: 20, sex: male}]},
    {name: 'John', details: [{age: 25, sex: male}]},
];

let newArray = data.map(value=> value.details[0])
// newArray is [{age: 20, sex: male}, {age: 25, sex: male}]
```